# How to remove Credentials section from Jenkins homepage?

Tags: jenkins, apache2, jenkins-plugins

I currently have the Jenkins Credentials plugin installed on an apache webserver. The global jenkins security is set to "logged in users can do everything" and anonymous users can only read.

I want to remove this section from the homepage on the left side:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you are mixing three different items - authentication, authorization and credentials. You have set so any authenticated user has full access. Credentials are typically used to interact with 3rd party apps. As @drgrog says, you can (and should) enable Matrix, Project or role based security in any multi-user environment and constrain user's capabilities via that. Credentials is one of the items you can constrain.You really don't want "everyone" to have admin capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Configure Global Security', try changing from 'Logged in users can do anything' to 'Matrix-based security' or 'Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy', and you should see a table that allows you to disable the credentials options for authenticated users.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/#configuring-credentials

Although if you're an admin I think it shows up regardless.